# What is ASN.1 DER tag value 0xA0?

Tags: asn.1, der

Here is an example of a certificate encoded in ASN.1 DER

```
30 82 01 8F 30 81 F9 **A0** 03 02 01 02 02 01 01 30
0D 06 09 2A 86 48 86 F7 0D 01 01 05 05 00 30 0D
31 0B 30 09 06 03 55 04 03 0C 02 43 41 30 20 17
0D 31 33 30 39 31 35 31 35 33 35 30 32 5A 18 0F
32 31 31 33 30 39 32 32 31 35 33 35 30 32 5A 30
0D 31 0B 30 09 06 03 55 04 03 0C 02 43 41 30 81
9F 30 0D 06 09 2A 86 48 86 F7 0D 01 01 01 05 00
03 81 8D 00 30 81 89 02 81 81 00 8D 80 B5 8E 80
8E 94 D1 04 03 6A 45 1A 54 5E 7E EE 6D 0C CB 0B
82 03 F1 7D C9 6F ED 52 02 B2 08 C3 48 D1 24 70
C3 50 C2 1C 40 BC B5 9D F8 E8 A8 41 16 7B 0B 34
1F 27 8D 32 2D 38 BA 18 A5 31 A9 E3 15 20 3D E4
0A DC D8 CD 42 B0 E3 66 53 85 21 7C 90 13 E9 F9
C9 26 5A F3 FF 8C A8 92 25 CD 23 08 69 F4 A2 F8
7B BF CD 45 E8 19 33 F1 AA E0 2B 92 31 22 34 60
27 2E D7 56 04 8B 1B 59 64 77 5F 02 03 01 00 01
30 0D 06 09 2A 86 48 86 F7 0D 01 01 05 05 00 03
81 81 00 0A 1C ED 77 F4 79 D5 EC 73 51 32 25 09
61 F7 00 C4 64 74 29 86 5B 67 F2 3D A9 39 34 6B
3C A9 92 B8 BF 07 13 0B A0 9B DF 41 E2 8A F6 D3
17 53 E1 BA 7F C0 D0 BC 10 B7 9B 63 4F 06 D0 7B
AC C6 FB CE 95 F7 8A 72 AA 10 EA B0 D1 6D 74 69
5E 20 68 5D 1A 66 28 C5 59 33 43 DB EE DA 00 80
99 5E DD 17 AC 43 36 1E D0 5B 06 0F 8C 6C 82 D3
BB 3E 2B A5 F1 94 FB 53 7B B0 54 22 6F F6 4C 18
1B 72 1C
```

What does the highlighted tag `0xA0` mean? What type it encodes?

The next value is `0x03` which is the length of the `0xA0` tag.
But the next byte after the length is actually `INTEGER` type - `0x02`.

Who can explain this?

Comment: Is there a typo?  A value of 0xA0 is highlighted.  You talk about 0x0A in your post.

Comment: Have you considered consulting the documentation?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`0xA0` is a `Context Specific` tag. In your example it contains an integer as you correctly deduced. In ASN.1 you can have 4 encoding of class of the 1-byte tag (more in section 8.1.2.2 of [ITU-T X.690](http://www.itu.int/itu-t/recommendations/rec.aspx?rec=X.690)):

- Universal *(`00xxxxxx`)*
- Application *(`01xxxxxx`)*
- Context-specific *(`10xxxxxx`)*
- Private *(`11xxxxxx`)*

Personally I've never seen anything other than Universal (i.e sequence, integer, octet string) and context-specific.

You can explore the structure of the certificate by using [ASN.1 Editor](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4910/ASN-Editor). I've selected the context specific tag here:

[image: Screenshot of ASN.1 Editor]

Comment: What does "Context specific" actually mean here? And what distinguishes `0xa0=0b10100000` from other values that fit `0b10xxxxxx`, which would also be context specific?

Answer (score 1):

**specific answer**

To answer the specific question:
0xA0 is a 1-byte ASN.1 tag meaning constructed CONTEXT-specific item #0.
"constructed" means it will contain other entries.
But its meaning beyond that depends on the context it is used in.

**general answer**

There are four classes to ASN.1 tags, encoded in the two topmost bits of the first tag byte.

UNIVERSAL is for the predefined tag types. That means both the tree-leaves which contain actual data (INTEGER, OID, OCTET STRING and so on), and the standard "constructed" container types SEQUENCE and SET. SEQUENCE (0x30) is what you encounter a lot.

APPLICATION, CONTEXT and PRIVATE tag classes are a different beast. The constructed/primitive flag at bit 5 = 0x20 still applies, but beyond that, there are no "universal" pre-defined tag value meanings. So in most cases, the lower bits of the tag will start at 0, counting up.

There is no formal requirement I know of which of these three classes needs to be used when. But the idea is this:

- APPLICATION for wide use within an application context,
- PRIVATE for data proprietary and internals to an organisation,
- CONTEXT for use in a specific, defined context.

Cryptography standards like the X.509 and the PKCS series use CONTEXT.

The bias towards CONTEXT is also inherent in the ASN.1 specification; when defining an ASN.1 module, the CONTEXT keyword may be omitted - `[0]` means `CONTEXT[0]`. In contrast, APPLICATION and PRIVATE keywords are mandatory.

Another practical example is given with CHOICE implementations: the "outer" part of CHOICE being represented in an 0xA0 tag, the alternatives then numbered 0x80, 0x81 and so on - because their meaning applies within the CONTEXT of the outer tag.